# Java CurrenTimeMilis not matching

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am having an issue in my java program.

I am using timestamps to peform a query on the database, but I am getting the wrong timestamp.

On my VM, I have the date set to be pacific time:

```
date

Wed Oct 30 09:50:43 PDT 2013
```

also

```
timedatectl status

  Local time: Wed 2013-10-30 09:52:30 PDT
Universal time: Wed 2013-10-30 16:52:30 UTC
    Timezone: US/Pacific (PDT, -0700)
 NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
     DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                 Sun 2013-03-10 01:59:59 PST
                 Sun 2013-03-10 03:00:00 PDT
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
              Sun 2013-11-03 01:59:59 PDT
              Sun 2013-11-03 01:00:00 PST
```

but when my program does system.getCurrentMilis() is is returning the following timestamp:

```
2013-10-30 11:47:16.884
```

I am not sure why this is the case.  If someone could tell me what is wrong or what i could check that would be awesome

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
//- Get maximum timestamp from previous query
Timestamp maxTimestamp = (new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() ) ;


//- Compute query parameters (see notes above)
Timestamp lowerLimit = new Timestamp( maxTimestamp.getTime() - 500) ;
System.out.println("lowerLimit=" + lowerLimit ) ;
Timestamp upperLimit = new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("upperLimit=" + upperLimit ) ;
```

Comment: [`.getCurrentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) doesn't return a `String` it returns a `long`, whatever you are doing to convert the `long` into a `String` is using a `TimeZone`, probably the default. Show that code. What is your default `TimeZone` set to?

Comment: added in some edit. but i don't switch it to a String, i just do print out the Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

system.getCurrentMilis()  gives the a long representing amount ms from the start of 1970 in GMT. When you parse it into a string you most likely adjust it by Timezone and daylight savings.